# Не срабатывает АЯКС в Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, javascript, ajax, php

Здравствуйте, установил к себе на сайт фансибокс, с его помощью хотел создать опрос. Всё красиво прописал, вот таким вот образом:

```
<div id="opros">
    <div class="three_quarter">
        <h1>Пацаны это опрос!</h1>
        <img src="images/opros.png" style="float: right;" width="320" alt="">
        <div><b>Введите Ф И О:</b><input id="fio" type="text" name="fio" /><br /></div>

        <div style="padding: 20px 0 0 0;"><b>Вопросы:</b></div>

        <div style="padding: 10px 0;"><b>Вы:</b> 
            Мужчина<input id="sex" type=radio name="sex" value="Мужчина"> 
            Женщина<input id="sex" type=radio name="sex" value="Женщина"></div>

        <div style="padding: 10px 0;">  
        <b>Зачем вы поступали в Универ?</b><br>
        <input id="zachem" type=radio name="zachem" value="Чтобы учится и узнавать новое!"> Чтобы учится и узнавать новое!<br>
        <input id="zachem" type=radio name="zachem" value="Познакомится с новыми людьми."> Познакомится с новыми людьми.<br>
        <input id="zachem" type=radio name="zachem" value="Просто получить диплом, я и так знаю больше чем преподают!"> Просто получить диплом, я и так знаю больше чем преподают!<br>
        </div>

        <div style="padding: 10px 0;">  
        <b>Оцените уровень получаемых знаний в нашем университете:</b><br>
        <input id="raiting" type=radio name="raiting" value="Ужасно преподают, ничё не понятно!"> Ужасно преподают, ничё не понятно!<br>
        <input id="raiting" type=radio name="raiting" value="Преподают нормально, но можно и лучше!"> Преподают нормально, но можно и лучше!<br>
        <input id="raiting" type=radio name="raiting" value="Мне всё нравится, преподают отлично, всё понятно!"> Мне всё нравится, преподают отлично, всё понятно!<br>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
        <div style="padding: 10px 0; float: left;"> 
        <b>Как вам сайт?</b><br>
        <input id="rait" type=radio name="rait" value="Очень плохо"> Очень плохо<br>
        <input id="rait" type=radio name="rait" value="Не надо"> Не надо<br>
        <input id="rait" type=radio name="rait" value="Общепит"> Общепит<br>
        <input id="rait" type=radio name="rait" value="В самый раз"> В самый раз<br>
        <input id="rait" type=radio name="rait" value="Очень круто"> Очень круто<br>
        <input id="rait" type=radio name="rait" value="ШЕДЕВР!"> ШЕДЕВР!<br>
        </div>

        <p id="alert" style="margin-top: 75px; width: auto; margin-left: 250px">Чисто для теста!</p>

        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"><input id="opr" type="submit" value="Отправить" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Пытаюсь передать из него данные через jquery в форму отправки на емейл написанную на ПХП. Вот так у меня прописана данная функция:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#opr").click(function(){
            var fio = $("#fio").val();
            var sex = $("#sex").val();
            var zachem = $("#zachem").val();
            var raiting = $("#raiting").val();
            var rait = $("#rait").val();

            $.post("../scripts/mail.php",
                {
                    fio: fio,
                    sex: sex,
                    zachem: zachem
                    raiting: raiting
                    rait: rait  
                },
                function(data){
                    $("#al").html(data);
                }
            );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Но в окошко в fancybox никаких данных данный скрипт не возвращает... Если запустить данную конструкцию просто, не в модальном окошке fancybox, то всё работает, данные возвращаются сообщение отправляется на мыло. Рылся в поисковиках, решение данной проблемы так и не нашёл:(

Вот с помощью такой вот ссылки вызывается модальное окно

```
<a class="various" href="#opros">Опрос</a>
```

И собственно сам php скрипт:

```
<?php
```

if (isset($_POST)) {

```
$fio = ($_POST['fio']);
$sex = ($_POST['sex']);
$zachem = ($_POST['zachem']);
$raiting = ($_POST['raiting']);
$rait = ($_POST['rait']);

    if ($fio != ''){

        $to = "sdggs@mail.ru";
        $subject = "Robot";
        $message = "<html><head></head><body> 
                    На сайте ответили на вопросы! <br><br> 
                    <table width=100% border=0> 
                    <tr><td width=10><b>Полученные ответы:</b></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><b>Ф И О:</b></td><td>".$fio."</td><td>".$sex."</td>
                    <tr><td><b>Зачем вы поступали в Универ:</b></td><td> ".$zachem."<br></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><b>Получаемые знания:</b></td><td> ".$raiting." </td></tr>
                    <tr><td><b>Оценка сайту:</b></td><td> ".$rait." </td></tr>
                    </tr></table><br> 
                    </body></html>";
        $headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html;";
        $headers .= "From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>\r\n";
        $headers .= "Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com\r\n";
        $headers .= "Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com\r\n";
        mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        echo "Спасибо за то, что прошли наш опрос, это информация очень важна для нас!";

    } else {
        echo "Вы не заполнили поле Ф И О !";
    }
```

}
?>

Прошу помощи, очень необходимо сделать чтобы порос всплывающий в модальном окне fancybox работал и отправлял данные в данный пхп скрипт и возвращал их. Такое проворачиваю первый раз в жизни... 
Fancybox 2й версии.

Comment: комментариев ограниченное количество, поэтому приходится в другом месте писать.

А перенести довольно просто. Просто создаёте специальный файл .js, в нём все скрипты пишете, и его подключаете так же, как и любой другой: <script src="new.js"></script> Только после jquery, конечно же.

Comment: @Елена Левина, Спасибо вам большое за помощь! Очень вам признателен! Всё работает как необходимо)) Сейчас буду пробовать всё кидать в 1н файлик))

Comment: @Елена Левина, а не могли бы помочь еще вот с этим вопросом? Сюда к сожалению не влез такой пост:( http://hashcode.ru/questions/286959/php-передаются-одни-и-те-же-данные-через-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ: поместите скрипт, отправляющий результаты опроса, тоже в окошко фэнсибокса, рядом с формой.

Вот почему у вас сейчас не работает: на момент, когда работает скрипт

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#opr").click(function(){
        …
```

у вас в DOM ещё не существует элемента #opr. Fancybox берёт образец кода и создаёт новые элементы, на какоторые обработчики ещё не назначены. Поэтому на нажатие кнопки и нет никакой реакции.

Отсюда второй вариант: задействовать колбэки самого фэнсибокса.

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterShow: function(){
        $("#opr").click(function(){
            // обрабатываем клик.
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: @Елена Левина, Не работает. Вот как у меня получилось: 

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".various").fancybox({
      afterShow: function(){
    $("#opr").click(function(){
     var fio = $("#fio").val();
     var sex = $("#sex").val();
     var zachem = $("#zachem").val();
     var raiting = $("#raiting").val();
     var rait = $("#rait").val();
     
     $.post("../scripts/mail.php",
      {
       fio: fio,
       sex: sex,
       zachem: zachem
       raiting: raiting
       rait: rait 
      },
      function(data){
       $("#al").html(data);
      }
     );
    });
      };
 });
})

Comment: показывайте. Ссылку на сайт с ошибкой.

Comment: @Елена Левина, http://keh192.bget.ru/ вот, нажимаю на пункт меню опрос даже модальное окно не открывается:(

Comment: для начала посмотрите в веб-инспектор.

Синтаксическую ошибку следует устранить.

Comment: @Елена Левина, я видел инспектор, только через него я не могу понять в каком именно месте ошибка. Это из-за нее ничего не работает?

Comment: Вероятно. А ещё попробуйте сделать html и js по разным файлам. В большинстве случаев это правильное решение, которое здорово упрощает отладку.

Comment: ну не, скайп мне запускать — это домой идти, на планшете он плохо работает. А домой неохота, на берегу приятнее :) А во вконтактике регистрироваться неохота.

Но помочь — это с удовольствием. Денежка вряд ли поможет, а вот если вынесете js в отдельный файл, удобнее будет отладить это безобразие.

Comment: @Елена Левина, Всё! Заработало!!)) Действительно косяк был в ошибке из-за синтаксиса, не поставил запятую, когда описывал переменные в скрипте)) 
Скажите, а как перенести все эти мои нагромождения в один js файлик? Перенести то я их перенесу, и потом в Хэдере подключу как и jquery этот файлик, но при нажатии на кнопки будет ли он работать? Или надо какое то дополнительное обращение к нему прописывать?